# inno ide component selected by types

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup

Inno ide for example,
have two types which specifies some components but I don't want to list all components same list,
user select first type then i want only list first type's files and if select second type then I want only list second  type's files.

```
[Types]
Name: "sunucu"; Description: "Sunucu Bileşenleri";Flags: iscustom
Name: "istemci"; Description: "İstemci Bileşenleri" 

[Components]
Name: "readme"; Description: "Envanter Tanımlama Aracı"; Types: istemci
Name: "readme\de1"; Description: "Yetkili Kullanıcı"; Flags: exclusive; Types: istemci
Name: "readme\de2"; Description: "Genel Kullanıcı"; Flags: exclusive; Types: istemci
Name: "Jhe"; Description: "Jenerik Harita Editörü"; Types: istemci 
Name: "Mim"; Description: "Model İşletim Motoru"; Types: sunucu
Name: "OSSB"; Description: "Ortam Şartları Sunucu Birimi";  Types: sunucu
Name: "SIM_ART_PACKAGE"; Description: "Simülasyon Analiz ve Raporlama Aracı"; Types: istemci 
Name: "SIM_PACKAGE"; Description: "Simülasyon Arayüz Modülü";  Types: istemci
Name: "SPM"; Description: "Simülasyon Planlama Modülü";  Types: istemci
Name: "VTKB"; Description: "Simülasyon Kayıt Modülü";  Types: sunucu
Name: "VSMS"; Description: "Simülasyon Koşturma Servisi";  Types: sunucu
Name: "VSMS\s1"; Description: "SKS KAYIT"; Types: sunucu
Name: "VSMS\s2"; Description: "SKS";  Types: sunucu
Name: "VSMS\s3"; Description: "SKS OYNATMA";  Types: sunucu
```

Answer (score 0):

Inno can not hide/show components based on the type selected, and `[Types]` are not designed to completely change how the install works.

If the two types are completely different with no overlap, you're best off doing two separate installs, or have a custom page before hand asking which mode you want to install into and useing a `check:` function to determine whether to show them or not.

Comment: Thnks, "using a check function to determine whether to show them or not inno ide" how i do it?

Comment: I don't know about using InnoIDE, but INNO itself [explains check functions in detail in the help files](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptcheck.htm).